# Plotting the path through a 2d slice of an electric field

Tags: python, vector, physics

I have a piece of code that randomly scatters a range of point charges on the xy plane at z=0, and then determines the electric field above the charges at z=1. I won't include the code as it is long and fairly cumbersome, but for visualisation purposes here is a plot of the random assortment of 4 charges:

[image: iii]

The vector field is stored in terms of two 2d arrays, Ex and Ey. What I need to do next is to plot the path of a negative charge, randomly thrown into the plot above. I have done some random walks in the past and think the syntax would have to go something like this (written just in words for now)

Randomly generate an x and y co ordinate within relevant limits

```
for i in range(1, number_of_steps)

     walkpathx[i]=walkpath[i-1]+Ex_at_that_co_ordinate
     walkpathy[i]=walkpath[i-1]+Ey_at_that_co_ordinate
```

The issue I'm having is getting Ex_at_that_co_ordinate - the random initial position will give me an arbitrary number, but my vector field is not continuous so I'm not sure how to get my co ordinates to pick out the Efield at that point. Any help would be much appreciated, and apologies if I've formatted anything wrong. Some important points - we ignore any z components and imagine the charge is stuck in the xy plane at z=1, and ignore inertia and mass effects, its literally just meant to be a walk following the field starting at a random point.

Comment: Plotting a vector field (the title), and plotting the path of a particle in that field (the body of your question) are different questions.  Could you edit and clear up which you want?  Also, a particle in an electric field feels a force, which gives rise to acceleration.  It doesn't just walk the field lines.  The initial velocity of the particle and its mass are also important.

Comment: My bad, I had originally started typing this out last night for the field plot but managed to figure it out on my own which is why the title was wrong. For this problem we are told to ignore inertia and mass, and treat initial velocity as 0 so its just a walk following the field lines. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: The title is better now.  Ignore inertia and mass?  I wouldn't know where to begin.  Must not be a physics class ?

Comment: It's for a computational physics module, the idea is to just follow the field lines ignoring inertia effects.

Comment: Since this model is ignoring inertia, etc, I suggest using simple [bilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) to calculate the field vector at non-grid points.

Comment: There is a whole StackExchange website dedicated to such questions - [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

For a given position of the charges and a random initial position of the particle, *not on the grid* the simplest choice is to compute the field *ex-novo*:

```
ex, ey = E(x,y,P) # where P = [(x0, y0, c0), (x1, y1, c1), ...]
```

If you're not allowed to do this, you have to resort to interpolation; which kind of interpolation? in my opinion that's a matter that does not pertain to SO.

In general you have to choose the four adjacent points in the grid, pick the EF values and suitably combine them... If you're in trouble with that, edit your Q accordingly (or start a new one).